# Python separating the result of combinations

Tags: python, combinations

I have the following code I took from Geeksforgeeks.org to obtain combinations of a list:

```
from itertools import combinations

def comb(lper,n):
# A Python program to print all
# combinations of given length
 
# Get all combinations of list
# and length n
    b = combinations(lper, n)

    return b

lper = [i for i in range(-999,1000)]

lcomb = list(comb(lper,2))
print(lcomb)
```

This returns me

```
"[(-999, -998), (-999, -997), (-999, -996), (-999, -995), (-999, -994), (-999, -993)...]"
```

When I try to assign each number of a pair to a variable:

```
for i in lcomb:
    a = lcomb[i][0]
    b = lcomb[i][1]
```

I get the error

```
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"
```

I read the documentation of tuples and it is how we iterate through them. Am I not able to list a tuple of a list?
Sorry if this has been covered, I was not able to find it anywhere.

Comment: You are doing something like `lcomb[(-999, -998)]`, what do you actually want?

Comment: @ynkxsjmh I want to be able to use each number in a variable.
Like a =-999, b= -998. a= -999, b=-997, etc

Comment: Not related to your problem, but it's not really worthwhile defining your own function `comb`. It's just as easy to directly call the itertools function directly: `combinations(lper, n)` instead of `comb(lper, n)`. (Generally, geeksforgeeks.org isn't great for Python. The code usually works but it isn't written in the best or most natural way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing the list with each tuple, for example in the first iteration it would be:

```py
a = lcomb[(-999, -998)][0]
b = lcomb[(-999, -998)][1]
```

This is of course not working. I think you were assuming `i` is the index. To make it work that way, use:

```py
for i in range(len(lcomb)):
    a = lcomb[i][0]
    b = lcomb[i][1]
```

If it's only about accessing the first and second element of each tuple in the list, you could simply use:

```py
for a, b in lcomb:
    # do something here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate function. Like this

```
for i, lcomb_tuple in enumerate(lcomb):
  ...
```

"i" is an index in lcomb list.
"lcomb_tuple" is a tuple from lcomb.
If you don't need the lcomb_tuple, you can replace it to "_" like that:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(lcomb):
  ...
```